# Reference for the bite force for Nile Crocodile

Tags: zoology, bio-mechanics

The (maximal) bite force of the **Nile Crocodile** (*Crocodylus niloticus*) is estimated around **22,000 Newton** (refer to [YouTube interview with Ofer Kobi, a crocodile conservation ranger and croc farm owner, time 7:50-8:00, Hebrew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYnPVHqooFk) , where he estimates the bite force as above 2 metric tons). However, I didn't find a proper reference for this. Dr. Gregory Erickson measured the bite forces of a 5.2 meters long Saltwater Crocodile (*Crocodylus porosus*) and obtained a value of about 16,000+ Newton and estimated a 6.7 meters long Saltwater Crocodile can exert a bite twice as strong (about 34,000 Newton). See [Paper by Gregory Erickson et al.](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0031781) Interesting to note that Erickson measured small Nile Crocodile (total body length < 3 meters) so it does not represent the bite force of a full adult big crocodile.

**Remarks on units of force:**

1 Newton = 1 kg * 1 meter / sec^2

$1 \ \mathrm{Newton} = \frac{\mathrm{kg} \times \mathrm{meter}}{\mathrm{second}^2}$

1 Newton = 0.224808943 lbf = 0.225 lbf (pound-force)

10,000 Newton is approximately 1 tonne-force (1 tonne = 1 metric ton = 1000 kg)

Comment: Where did you get your estimates from?

Comment: From an interview with an owner of a crocodile farm.

Comment: An interview you've conducted yourself? An interview that has been diffused on TV? Do you have a link to this interview or some document where we can find direct quote or something?

Comment: No, an interview on TV. It was held in Hebrew. Since he is not a scientist I am looking for a better reference for the bite force of a Nile Crocodile. It seems strange that no body measured the bite force of a 5+ meters nile croc.

Comment: You can still link to the interview (or at least refer to the emission name and date of appearance). It really is always a good habit to link to your sources and it shows that you're not just throwing random number out of the void. You can also link to Erickson's study. Good format will increase your chances of getting people to care about your post. Good luck!

Comment: Here it is: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYnPVHqooFk) Time: 7:50-8:00

Comment: I sent an e-mail regarding this question to Dr. Gregory Erickson. I did not receive an answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a video by Brady Barr ([video in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=987EEJoVZwE)) measuring **5000 lbf** for an adult Nile Crocodile. This is equivalent to **22.24 kN** (more than 2.2 tonnes of force). This result is also refered [here](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/close-up-view-inside-a-nile-crocodile-mouth-high-res-stock-photography/102071730) (Getty Images).

[image: Nile Crocodile, image from Wikipedia] Source: [Gianfranco Gori, Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NileCrocodile--Etiopia-Omo-River-Valley-01.jpg)