# Bite Force of Triceratops

Tags: palaeontology, bio-mechanics, dinosaurs

Estimations (or measurements) of bite force is usually conducted for toothy predators like sharks, theropod dinosaurs and crocodiles. For example: *Tyrannosaurus* had a bite force of about 57 kN (about 5.7 tonne-force) while a 5.2 meters long Saltwater Crocodile (*Crocodylus porosus*) recorded a 16,700 Newton bite (by Gregory M. Erickson). See my earlier question [Reference for the bite force for Nile Crocodile](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74245/reference-for-the-bite-force-for-nile-crocodile) for reference.

However, although paleontologists agree herbivore ceratopsian dinosaur *Triceratops* had quite a strong bite due to large jaw muscles anchored to (part of) the frill, and sharp hard beak. However, as far as I am aware, no one ever tried to quantify how strong is *Triceratops* bite. But maybe there are some estimations in paleontological literature and scientific research. So to sum-up my question:

> What is the bite force of a fully-grown bull *Triceratops*?

Size for reference: *Triceratops* length was 8-9 meters and weighed 6-12 metric tonnes.

Comment: these may be helpful https://www.jstor.org/stable/2406631?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents and https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/744f/48001115d764d2ff4ad9a47de599900bf531.pdf

Comment: A Nile Crocodile bite force was measured to be 5000 lbf (22.24 kN) by Dr. Brady Barr. The bite force of T. rex is about 3 times higher.